# OSX Mavericks Textmate 2 install permissions error

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-mavericks, textmate, textmate2

I've been using textmate happily for a long time now but after installing the newest version of textmate 2.0 I'm receiving the following error when i open the app.

The file could not be saved because you don't have permission.
To view or change permissions select the item in finder and choose file get info.

So I'm not trying to change any particular file I'm just trying to open text mate.

Is textmate trying to create a system file for its own uses and is running into this error or is it a file the would automatically open or something else?

RUNNING ON: OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)

Answer (score 0):

> Is textmate trying to create a system file for its own uses and is running into this error or is it a file the would automatically open or something else?

You can hold shift (⇧) to skip session restore, that will rule out the second. Though TextMate shouldn’t *save* a file during launch, nor need any special permission.

It sounds more like something is messed up with your permissions or perhaps the TextMate application bundle (making the system report this error).

It was unclear from your description if the error is from TextMate itself or Finder. I would suggest you delete TextMate and download a new copy.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for opening TextMate 2 on Mavericks over an existing version.

I had the same problem installing TextMate 2 on Mavericks; program starts and quits with error concerning permissions.

After investigating the Console log I could determine that the file `/Library/Application Support/TextMate/ClipboardHistory.db` could not be created. I saved my `/Library/Application Support/TextMate` folder to another location and restarted `TextMate` with no problem. I then moved my bundles from the saved folder to the newly created `/Library/Application Support/TextMate` folder.